# Problem with links inside tag-wiki

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-wiki

Some links do not work in the tag wiki, but I'm not sure why:

Here is the laravel tag wiki:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/laravel/info

However the two links

- Laravel 4.1 Documentation
- Laravel 4 Documentation

Do not work.

I'm not sure this issue comes from SO or laravel.com.

Comment: This seems to be because http://laravel.com/docs/4-1 give 500 errors when coming from the outside (and SO is probably pinging laravel.com/docs/4-1 before linking). I will post an issue on laravel.com

Comment: I have submitted an issue on https://github.com/laravel/website/issues/9

Comment: No ping from SO, it's all their doing. Until (if) it's fixed, removing the dead links from the wiki. When you see it back feel free to suggest edit that brings the links back, or ping me here and I'll do it. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by the Laravel website:

```
$ curl -e http://stackoverflow.com/tags/laravel/info -D - -o /dev/null http://laravel.com/docs/4-1
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.14-1~quantal+1
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=deca72878q79bilsebutigrqo6; expires=Tue, 18-Mar-2014 15:51:28 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=deca72878q79bilsebutigrqo6; expires=Tue, 18-Mar-2014 15:51:28 GMT; path=/; httponly
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Tue, 18 Mar 2014 13:51:28 GMT
Location: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/laravel/info
Set-Cookie: docs_versions=eyJpdiI6IjFRbnlzMUdMSkE1a1dZTVQ1ZmdNajVNeXA4dnhQV1FmSUpxczZSUk92Ukk9IiwidmFsdWUiOiJxRFQrWWlWM21UQm9KcFBZdGFnZTlFZXhabVwvVnZMTW5weFc2bnBcL1J4M009IiwibWFjIjoiYmFlNGZmZjQ3M2ExYjUwNDMwMGY2YzQ5Y2JiNjBiNjQwNWQzMjY2NmM3YzcxMDUzYjI3MDM1YTM1NGI5YmM5MSJ9; path=/; httponly
Set-Cookie: docs_version=eyJpdiI6IlV2VFRHRkMrZlVuRkJPZ0drRTV6UVIrWjlBc0I4MzFYZ0FoUmdFbGhVWUE9IiwidmFsdWUiOiJONzNQXC9rR2p3VGxZXC9TWTJka2ZPWnVUR2ZuQzZKRmlsbWQ3b3YzOUxNYk09IiwibWFjIjoiMDYxNTllYzYxN2NiMDViODEwMzRmZmE1M2E4OTAyZjA4ZDk2MzY5YTg5MmIxZWU1YTBlODI4Yzc4MjYxNjk3ZSJ9; expires=Wed, 18-Mar-2015 13:51:28 GMT; path=/; httponly
```

It redirects right back to where you came from; the location header is set to whatever the referrer header in the request used.

If you visit the homepage first then use internal links, the site works, so this was not intentional.

Comment: Very smart: "we are closed, go back to where you came from".

Answer (score 1):

Martijn has it correct - this is an issue with the Laravel website.  Hopefully they deploy a fix for this soon.

Comment: Maybe it's deliberate on their part to prevent internal links to their site from outside. If that's the case, then don't expect a fix any time soon.